# Create A Task Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Good Afternoon:

I have written a PS Script that can create a task on my local machine; however, it is my intention to have this configure a task on multiple machines from a list. I cannot seem to find a way on how to do this. I did see something on using New-CimSession, but I dont think that is what I am looking for...

Here is my script:

```
foreach ($confighost in (Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\*User*\Documents\Test.txt"))
{
#Check for existent script in Task Scheduler

$taskpath = "\\$confighost\c$\Windows\System32\Tasks\LocalUserCleanUp"
$testtask = Test-Path -path $taskpath

If ($testtask -eq $true)
    {

        #If Task is already present, Do Not Run

        Write-Host "CleanUp Task Listed in Task Scheduler On" $confighost ". Will not Implement Task..."

    }

else
    {

        #If Task Does Not Exist Create Task
        New-CimSession -ComputerName $confighost
        Write-Host "No CleanUp Task Listed in Task Scheduler, Creating Task..."
        $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "C:\Users\*Users*\Documents\ProfileCleanup.ps1"
        $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily  -At 2am
        $settings = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
        Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $settings -TaskName "LocalUserCleanUp" -Description "Checks user accounts nightly to see if they are older than 30 days"

    }
}
```

I look forward to your insight. Thanks again for all your assistance!

Comment: I think you to assign your New-CimSession to a variable, and execute the operations on that variable

Comment: Hmmm... Do you mean to do something like $PCTask = New-CimSession -ComputerName $confighost and then infront of Register -ScheduledTask  as so: $PCTask(Register-ScheduledTask...) Something along those lines... I guess Im having trouble following...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7) to execute your task creation code on a target server:

```
$cred = Get-Credential # There are a number of methods to automate reading the credential from a file
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName server01, server02, server0X {
  # Your task creation code here
}
```

If you have any variables defined in your local session that you need available in the remote code, you can reference them in your `Invoke-Command` [`ScriptBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7) reference the variable from the [`using` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7#the-using-scope-modifier) by prefixing the local variable with `$using:`.

Comment: I am reading up on Invoke-Command now! I will post again if I continue to struggle. Thank you both for your assistance. Ill be sure to post the working code here as the final answer!

Comment: So I am attempting to use the use the Invoke command and I get the following error: ```Connecting to remote server PC failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete 
the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, ...
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: :String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken```

Comment: What Im getting at, is there a way to elevate my privileges on the remote host so that I can configure this task remotely through this script...

Comment: Either the name of the server you're connecting to is wrong, it's not in DNS, or you are getting firewalled.

Comment: If UAC is enabled in your environment, take a look at [`New-PSSessionConfigurationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionconfigurationfile?view=powershell-5.1).